# How to calculate age in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I'm trying to create a calculated field for the age of an asset (say, an article or youtube video) in Data Studio. So basically it's the current date less the creation date, hopefully leaving me with the number of days since the item has been created.

Google's sample for this is:

```
DATE_DIFF(TODATE(end_time, 'NANOS', '%Y-%m-%d'), TODATE(start_time, 'MICROS', '%Y%m%d'))
```

Which doesn't work despite any tweaks I make to it. Any ideas?

Comment: What types are `end_time` and `start_time`. Could you post some example values for them? The problem is likely that those values don't match with what `TODATE` expects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way that it can be achieved is by using the New Date Time functions released in the [17 Sep 2020 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6311467#sep-17-2020).

The [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below uses the [`DATETIME_DIFF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9698749) function to get the difference between the [`CURRENT_DATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9736967) and the Date field (titled `Creation Date` in this Report), and can display the result as required, based on the third input of the [`DATETIME_DIFF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9698749) function, such as `DAY` or `YEAR`:

### 1) DAY

```
DATETIME_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), Creation Date, DAY)
```

### 2) YEAR

```
DATETIME_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), Creation Date, YEAR)
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c862ac1e-7cee-4be5-9aaa-516d0d0617b7) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`TODAY()` worked for me.

Here is an example for calculating date of birth:

```
FLOOR(DATE_DIFF(TODAY(), TODATE(date_of_birth, '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y-%m-%d')) / 365)
```

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78200216